# Creating a datetime column from 2 float columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I'm trying to combine 2 float columns into a datetime column in a pandas dataframe.   For example, column year would have the value `2018.0`, column month would have `1.0`, and I would want the output to be 1/1/2018 in datetime.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: The name of the columns with floars are "IncMth" and "IncYr".  I've tried to convert to a string df["IncMth"].astype(int)+"/1/"+df['IncYr'].apply(str).str[0:4] and then apply the to_datetime function.   Also, tried to bring the floats into the datetime.date fucntion (datetime.date(df['IncYr'],df["IncMth"],1) but that doesn't work.  Sure there is probably an easy solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed your dataframe to [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) after assigning a `day` series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2018.0, 1.0], [2017.0, 5.0], [2019, 3.0], [2017, 12.0]],
                  columns=['year', 'month'])

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1))

print(df)

     year  month   datetime
0  2018.0    1.0 2018-01-01
1  2017.0    5.0 2017-05-01
2  2019.0    3.0 2019-03-01
3  2017.0   12.0 2017-12-01
```

Note this relies on strict naming conventions: `year`, `month`, `day` is an acceptable combination. If necessary, you can rename columns via [`pd.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

Comment: Wow I like your solution MUCH better than mine. Thanks for sharing :)